# Game crashes when opening crates

Tags: ios, star-wars-tiny-death-star

Sometimes, when I open my crates, my game crashes. I've read, that the reason for that is that there is a level/character in it, and my game doesn't have enough active memory to open it. But: all my levels are closed, I've tried to kick all my VIPs out but it changed nothing, all my other apps are closed, restarting my phone didn't help.
Now about the char/level thing. My first rare cargo was Wookie arms, a level. I got it while already experiencing the problem. So I'd have said that the game crashes randomly, if I didn't spend a day farming Kashyyyk, getting all the chars, never finding the Shack and only crashing all the time.

Help?

Answer (score 1):

I have had good luck only opening crates in airplane mode - I still crash sometimes, but far less often (I am on iOS if that makes a difference).  But I'd say that your experience of the game crashing frequently is not uncommon, and appears to be happening more and more from the messages posted here.